# Whats the short hand for assigning a value to a field that is a pointer type

Tags: pointers, go, structure

I pulled this off:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type test struct {
    A *int
    B string
}

func main() {
    x := 1
    var A test
    A.B = "hello"
    A.A = &x
    fmt.Printf("%s, %v", A.B, *A.A)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/iMsFBTWkRJU

I know using `x:=1` and `A.A = &x` is over doing it. How can I modify and make it simpler?

Thanks for your time

Comment: the shorthand is writing a function if you need it.

Comment: The linked code is an extremely contrived example. Maybe with a real use-case it might be easier to offer advice about your particular situation.

Answer (score 1):

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

type T struct {
    A *int
    B string
}

func newT(a int, b string) *T {
    return &T{A: &a, B: b}
}

func main() {
    t := newT(1, "Hello")
    fmt.Printf("%s, %v", t.B, *t.A)
}
```

Output:

```
Hello, 1
```